# Connectedness of the domain in Identity Theorem

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, roots, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be a complex-valued holomorphic function defined on an open set $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, which is not identically zero.

Let $S=\{a\in \Omega :f(a)=0\}$=set of all zeros of $f$.

We know that $S$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}$ as $f$ is continuous. Also, one can easily prove that $S$ is isolated.
Therefore, we have

### $f\not\equiv0 \implies S$ is isolated.

Hence the contrapositive of the statement is

### $S$ is not isolated $\implies f\equiv 0 $

But, $S$ is not isolated implies that is there exists a point of $S$ which is not isolated. But, we also know that $S$ is closed, hence there exists a point of $S$ which is a limit point of $S$.

### $S$ has a limit point in $S$ $\implies f\equiv 0$

---

### Question:

But, I know that the above statement is not true. We need the domain $\Omega$ to be connected for the above statement to be true. But I am unable to find any mistake in my argument. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you may only conclude that f has a non-isolated zero in $\Omega$, implies that f is identically zero in $\Omega$ provided $\Omega$ is connected.

Comment: @Alexandros Why do we require $\Omega$ to be connected?

Comment: If you consider $\Omega$ to be the disjoint union of two open sets A and B, you can take f to be identically 0 on A, and equal to some non-zero constant on B. Then, f is a holomorphic function which is not identically zero, but its zero set contains all of A.

Comment: @Alexandros I understand. But are you able to find a flaw in my logic (which doesn't require $\Omega$ to be connected)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let $\Omega$ be two disjoint open circles and constant with two different constants one $0$ and one $1$ e.g.

In all implications $\Omega$ was assumed to be connected from the start so you cannot drop it anywhere. A srtandard assumption in complex function theory (for holomorphic to be defined etc.) is that the function domain is a "Gebiet" (as it's called in German), i.e. open and connected. Any open set in $\mathbb{C}$ is a disjoint union of these.

Comment: To prove the first statement "$f\not\equiv 0$ and analytic in $\Omega$ $\implies S$ is isolated, we don't need $\Omega$ to be connected.

Comment: @Babai but the argument works only on a single component.

Comment: @Babai: To emphasize, that statement you just wrote in your comment is *false* if $\Omega$ fails to be connected. If $f=0$ on one component of $\Omega$ but has isolated zeroes on another component of $\Omega$, then, of course, your implication fails.